# Sending EOF shortcut: on what does it actually depend on?

Tags: terminal, shell, operating-systems, eof

It is common knowledge that on Linux to send EOF to a console program you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> while on Windows you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

However I suspect that this is not actually a feature of the OS, but rather of the terminal or shell or ... maybe something else (like gnu readline).

So what (sub)system/program translates these keys into EOF?

Comment: The shell you are running.

Comment: @DavidPostill Nah, it has nothing to do with the shell. It's the terminal

Comment: @oguzismail Windows `cmd` is a shell. It happens to run in a terminal (sometimes).

Comment: @DavidPostill the question is also about Unix; in Unix, *sh is the shell, and it has nothing to do with Ctrl+D. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character#Meaning_in_Unix)

Comment: It _still_ has nothing to do with the shell, because Cmd isn't the one performing this translation on Windows, either.

Comment: You may increase your chances for good answers by asking *separately* about the Windows mechanism and the Unix mechanism. My point is the current question requires a user who knows *both*. Users who know one xor another cannot create a good answer, unless they cooperate (community wiki?); they may step down. Or you may get two sets of half-answers. Separate questions would be on-topic here on Super User, still I expect [Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) to answer the Unix part more thoroughly. If you decide to ask there, mind [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310).